# How to replace union all in my TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I'm getting a data file with below format. I have to get a table stored with Item description.

I am looking for an ouput with CategoryID , Itemcode and Item description. Since the data for all the items is in the same row distingushed by category it's getting a little tricky.

```
CategoryID  Name    ItemCode1   ItemCode2   ItemCode3   ItemCode4   ItemCode5
   1        Test1   1234578     87BA1234                 ERR12345
   2        Test2   BAAA9AAJ                143PAAM
```

ItemDescription is stored as below:

```
Itemcode     ItemDesc
12345678     Item1
87BA1234     Item2
and so on
```

I'm able to get the output I want by Selecting each item and description separately and bind them with a union all. But I feel like there should be a better way to do it. Appreciate your guidance.

Edit: My T- SQL with union all

```
SELECT CategoryID, isnull(Item.ItemDescription, 'Unknown') as ItemDesc
            FROM 
            (
                SELECT CategoryID, ItemCode1 as code
                FROM ItemDesc
                UNION ALL       --AAAE9AAF
                SELECT  CategoryID, ItemCode2 as code
                FROM ItemDesc
                UNION ALL       --AAAG9AAF
                SELECT  CategoryID, ItemCode3 as code
                FROM ItemDesc
                UNION ALL       
                SELECT CategoryID, ItemCode4 as code
                FROM ItemDesc
                UNION ALL       
                SELECT  CategoryID, ItemCode5 as code
                FROM ItemDesc
            )tc
            LEFT JOIN @ItemDescription Item ON Item.ItemCode = tc.code
```

Comment: do you mind posting your query.

Comment: Can you show us the actual t-sql command you are running that has the union in it. Maybe it is just me, but your description isn't making too much sense. Are you saying that item_description is in another table? Is categoryID a foreign key or part of a foreign key? Basically I'm asking for more of an explanation. thanks.

Comment: where is `description` in your output. Please give sample data and expected output based on that.

Comment: @KamranFarzami I just edited my question with my tsql

Comment: @Utsav I have added the table structure of Item description table as well

Comment: What you really should do is fix your flawed data model (unless this is a staging table of information you need to process to get to your real database structure). No relational database should have fields like itemcode1, itemcode2, etc. That screams that you need a child table instead.

Comment: @HLGEM This is a staging table with which we build our real tables. Still I know this is a bad structrure. I'm trying to talk to folks out of this model. Till then I needed a fix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand it right, you want to unpivot your data.

Try using `CROSS APPLY`:

```
select
    t.categoryId,
    x.itemcode,
    d.itemDesc
from your_table t
cross apply (
    values (t.itemcode1),(t.itemcode2),(t.itemcode3),
           (t.itemcode4),(t.itemcode5)
    ) x (itemcode)
join ItemDescription d on x.itemcode = d.itemcode;
```

Comment: This should work. But the OP needs to check two things first before making the change, first that it returns the same results and second that it performs as well or better than the original.  These are things you need to do anytime you rewrite something using a different method.

Answer (score 2):

using [**`cross apply()`**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx) with `values()`:

```
select 
    t.CategoryId
  , t.Name
  , v.ItemCode
from t
cross apply (values (ItemCode1), (ItemCode2), (ItemCode3), (ItemCode4), (ItemCode5)
  ) v (ItemCode)
where isnull(ItemCode,'') <> ''
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/TFPP48713

returns:

```
+------------+-------+----------+
| CategoryId | Name  | ItemCode |
+------------+-------+----------+
|          1 | Test1 | 1234578  |
|          1 | Test1 | 87BA1234 |
|          1 | Test1 | ERR12345 |
|          2 | Test2 | BAAA9AAJ |
|          2 | Test2 | 143PAAM  |
+------------+-------+----------+
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. If I can accept both answers I could have accepted this one as well. I'm sorry!